# How to enable a combobox from another combobox in SENCHA/ext js?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, combobox, sencha-architect

I need to change something in Sencha, I need to add a second combobox that in the begining must be disable, that's ok no problem with that, but then I need that the first combobox will enable the second combobox when some items (not all) from the first combo is selected, it looks very simple.

Here is the code:

```
var formPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
  id: 'formanchor-form',
  title: 'Nuevo Gasto',
  bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
  width: 600,
  defaults: {
    width: 230
  },
  defaultType: 'textfield',
  renderTo: 'formulario',
  frame: true,
  items: [{
    xtype: 'combo',
    typeAhead: true,
    name: 'cboGasto',
    id: 'cboGasto',
    fieldLabel: 'Gastos',
    store: storeCbo,
    displayField: 'gasto',
    valueField: 'codigo',
    allowBlank: false,
    width: 250,
    mode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    emptyText: 'SELECCIONE',
    blankText: 'Debe seleccionar un gasto',
    forceSelection: true
  }, {
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Monto',
    name: 'txtMonto',
    id: 'txtMonto',
    maxLength: 7,
    allowBlank: false,
    minValue: 100,
    minText: 'El monto mínimo es 100',
    maxValue: 9999999,
    maxLengthText: 'El monto máximo es 9.999.999',
    blankText: 'El monto es requerido',
    width: 100
  }, {
    xtype: 'combo',
    typeAhead: true,
    name: 'CboDeudasReceptor',
    id: 'CboDeudasReceptor',
    fieldLabel: 'Receptor',
    store: storeCboR,
    displayField: 'receptor',
    valueField: 'codigo',
    allowBlank: false,
    width: 250,
    mode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    emptyText: 'SELECCIONE',
    blankText: 'Debe seleccionar un Receptor',
    forceSelection: true,
    disabled: true
  }],
  buttons: [{
    text: 'Agregar',
    handler: function() {
      var mon = Ext.getCmp('txtMonto').getValue();
      var gas = Ext.getCmp('cboGasto').getValue();
      if (mon.length == 0) {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Monto del Gasto', 'Debe Ingresar un monto para el gasto.');
        Ext.getCmp('txtMonto').focus();
        return false;
      }
      if (gas.length == 0) {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Gasto', 'Debe Seleccionar un gasto.');
        Ext.getCmp('cboGasto').focus();
        return false;
      }
      location.href = 'ingresa_gastos_lib.asp?cboGasto=' + gas + '&txtMontoPesos=' + mon + '&' + params();
    }
  }, {
    text: 'Volver',
    handler: function() {
      location.href = 'datos_deuda.asp?' + params();
    }
  }]
});
```

**UPDATE:**

If I put a listener in the first combo, then works partial like I want it, but the 2nd combo just work the dropdown but still looks like disabled, and I can´t edit. So the question now would be: How to put the 2nd combobox full operational.

```
listeners: {
  select: function(combo, record, index) {
    if (Ext.getCmp('cboGasto').getRawValue() == 'RECEPTOR: EMBARGO') {
      alert(Ext.getCmp('cboGasto').getRawValue());
      Ext.getCmp('CboDeudasReceptor').disabled = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `disabled` field to false does not a solution. It is just changing the value of the property in the object, but all visual styles are still there. You should use `setDisabled()` method of the combobox, or `enable()` and `disabled()` methods. So your listener should look like the following:

```
select: function (combo, record, index) {
    if (Ext.getCmp('cboGasto').getRawValue()=='RECEPTOR: EMBARGO'){
            alert(Ext.getCmp('cboGasto').getRawValue());
            Ext.getCmp('CboDeudasReceptor').setDisabled(false);
            //Or Ext.getCmp('CboDeudasReceptor').enable();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
items:[{
    xtype: "combobox",
    name: "TubeWellId",
    fieldLabel: "Tubewell",
    store: tube_well_store,
    allowBlank: false,
    displayField: "TubeWellName",
    valueField: "TubeWellId",
    queryMode: "local",
    forceSelection: true,
    listeners: {
        select: function (combo) {
            var getForm = this.up("form").getForm();
            if (combo.getValue() === 1) {
                getForm.findField("TubeWellDistance").setReadOnly(true);
            } else {
                getForm.findField("TubeWellDistance").setReadOnly(false);
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    xtype: "combobox",
    name: "TubeWellDistance",
    fieldLabel: "Tubewell Distance",
    store: tube_well_store,
    allowBlank: false,
    displayField: "DistanceName",
    valueField: "DistanceId",
    queryMode: "local",
    forceSelection: true,
}]
```